# Delete Reactions Text From Disqus

Tags: disqus

Anyone know where to delete the reactions text at the top of my blog with Wordpress Disqus? I want to keep the comments text but lose the reactions text.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Found it sorry - Dashboard-Settings-General

Answer (score 5):

You can always disable reactions within your settings: http://disqus.com/admin/settings/

Comment: I disabled reactions but they still show up on the main blog stream, but on on individual posts.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found out a fix?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem where mine said "X comments and X reactions." I tried everything. The answer from Ron- to de-activate and then re-activate worked for me.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to your blogger dashboard> layout. Delete the "Disqus for XXX" widget.
2. Go to your disqus admin page > settings > install.
3. Follow instructions and re-install disqus.

It should now just say X comments.

Answer (score 1):

After disabling reactions on the Disqus end, it required a quick 'deactivate' and then 'reactivate' of the plugin within wordpress before the text would update.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but since this wasn't fully resolved I thought I'd add my input. It's a year later, but I have had the same problem.

To solve it, what I had to do was disable reactions in Disqus' settings, deactivate the plugin, then activate it again. That did it for at least one person, so it's worth trying if anyone comes across this as well.

To disable reactions, head to http://disqus.com/admin/settings/ as Giannii has said and make sure 'Enable Reactions' is unchecked.